# Fortnite Discord Bot JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord

I'm working on my fortnite discord bot and I wanted to switch cosmetic API's. But the API I wanted to switch to AKA https://fortniteapi.io isn't letting me phrase the json with my code. Please someone help.

Here is my code:

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f"https://fortniteapi.io/items/list?name={item}", headers={'Authorization':'auth'}) as r:       
            try:
                json = await r.json()     
                for sub_dict in json['items']:
                    items = sub_dict
                    print(items)
                    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{items['id']}", description=f"{items['description']}")
                    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{items['name']}", inline=True)
                    embed.add_field(name="Type", value=f"{items['type']}", inline=True)
                    embed.add_field(name="Set", value=f"{items['set']}", inline=True)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Jonsey Bot | Created By ignBane#1828")
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            except Exception as e:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Oops, that wasn't supposed to happen.", color=0xff0000)
                embed.add_field(name="Error:", value=f"``\n{e}\n``", inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text="Jonsey Bot | Created By ignBane#1828")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my json for the website.

```
{'result': True, 'lang': 'en', 'itemsCount': 1, 'items': [[{'id': 'CID_610_Athena_Commando_M_ShiitakeShaolin', 'type': 'outfit', 'name': 'Madcap', 'description': 'The master of mushrooms enters the fight.', 'rarity': 'epic', 'internalRarity': 'epic', 'price': 0, 'added': '2020-07-04', 'reactive': False, 'releaseDate': None, 'interest': 7.84, 'images': {'icon': 'https://media.fortniteapi.io/images/4a7f5d675a4949867abca11cbfe29206/transparent.png', 'full_size': 'https://media.fortniteapi.io/images/4a7f5d675a4949867abca11cbfe29206/featured.png', 'featured': None, 'background': 'https://media.fortniteapi.io/images/4a7f5d675a4949867abca11cbfe29206/background.png', 'full_background': 'https://media.fortniteapi.io/images/4a7f5d675a4949867abca11cbfe29206/background_full.en.png'}, 'video': None, 'gameplayTags': ['Cosmetics.UserFacingFlags.HasVariants', 'Cosmetics.Source.ItemShop', 'Cosmetics.Set.MushroomQueen', 'Cosmetics.Filter.Season.12'], 'set': 'Fungus King'}]]}
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What it should be doing is sending all the info, like name, type, set stuff like that. But instead the bot sends this "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" because of the error handling. Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indexing into your JSON incorrectly. `json['items']` contains a list, holding a list, holding a dictionary.

There's only one element either of the lists so I don't think looping over them is the right thing to do. Instead do something like:

```py
json = await r.json()
items = json['items'][0][0]
embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{items['id']}", description=f"{items['description']}")
# And so on...
```

The error message you're getting indicates that you're treating a list like you would a dictionary. Given that accessing elements from a list and dictionary both use square brackets, when you see that error message you'll want to look at your code and double check that you're working with the correct types.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that sub_dict is actually an array and not an object so try setting line 6 to

```
items = sub_dict[0]
```